# Playwright python, version 1.18 not found when installing

Tags: python, pip, playwright

S.O: Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7+ armv7l GNU/Linux (Raspberry PI)

Python version: 3.8

Pip version: pip 21.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

I'm trying to install playwright, using `pip install playwright` but this install version `0.162.2`, tried to specific a version `pip install playwright==1.18.1` [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/playwright/) but this doesn't find this version.

I tried updating and upgrading. But nothing...

`apt update && apt upgrade && pip install --upgrade pip`

Also tried with `/usr/bin/python3.8 -m pip install playwright`

```py
>>> from playwright._repo_version import version
>>> print(version)
0.162.2
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.piwheels.org is where wheels for Raspberry Pi are published, not PyPI. This is the list of wheels for "playwright": https://www.piwheels.org/project/playwright/ . Version  0.162.2 is the latest available release (click on "Show more releases").

To install from PyPI try to install from both PyPI and PiWheels:

```
pip install --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple/ playwright
```

Comment: I tried with yout line but same. Thanks! I figure out, it's because amrv71 is not supported by playwright